# Claims in JWT vs Claims Transformation in Resource

Tags: .net, authorization, jwt, claims-based-identity, identityserver3

I'm using IdentityServer3 as the authorization server in my architecture.

I have an API resource, which i grant my clients (web app and iOS app) access to via a resource scope.

**Question 1**: 
If i want to do claims-based authorization in my API (e.g a claim called `CanViewQuestions`, that only some users have), should i:

a) Use IdentityServer, e.g during authentication figure out if the user has that claim and add it to the JWT

b) Just put the subject (e.g userId) claim in the JWT, and look that up in the API and perform claims-transformation?

I'm currently doing b), but wondering if this should be performed by the authorization server (e.g IdSrv) itself?

Whats the recommended approach?

**Question 2**

If i have a background service (Azure Worker specifically) that i want to also give access to my API resource, i can use client credentials flow to give this service an access token. 
But then how can i give this service the same claim above (`CanViewQuestions`)? I basically want to have my API to ensure a given resource requires the claim `CanViewQuestions`, but i don't care if the client is the web app (e.g end user involved), or the client (no end user). If the requestor has the claim, good to go.

Am i going to have to:

a) Use claims-based transformation to see if the client is the service, then just add all the claims?

b) Embed the claims in the JWT (although i've read client credentials flow doesn't support claims)

c) Something else?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both cases I would recommend adding the API specific claims at the API - not inside the token.

Authorization specific data should always be added as close as possible to the resource you are trying to protect.